# Why does AX 2012 data import from staging to target always overwrite 1 record?

Tags: import, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a custom table that I am trying to import data into.  When importing into my staging table, I get 3 separate records.  When importing from staging to target, it will create 1 record (if there are no records) and then 'update' that record twice.  If there is already a record in the target, it will update that record 3 times.

I'm fairly certain this has something to do with this table(target) being a custom table, however, I can't figure out why the records always update.  They are unique records.

Comment: What unique value are you using for the update?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Are you using a primary key in the table, and if so are you using this as your select parameter when selecting for update? Also, are you using update_recordset or individually updating/inserting each item. Some code samples would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a relationship between the Staging and Target tables.  Once the correct relationship was set, everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you explain this in steps? thnks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it using InsertUpdate method in the TableMain entity Class. In insertupdate method check the values from target buffer and see if record exists in TableMain. If yes, then modify callinsertlogic to false, else make it true.

TableMain tableMain;

```
select RecId from tableMain where tableMain .Field1 == target.fiedl1 

if(tablemain.recid) Callinsertlogic = false; else callinsertlogic = true;
```

then call the super method `ret = super( ..,callinsertlogic,..)`.

Using this way I can do insert if record is new, update if existing record, without adding index in tablemain.